# MySql Users Export

Tags: mysql

I am migrating a MySql Server Instance to another physical server. I have transferred over all of the Databases via MySql Administrator but I do not see a way for me to export all of the Mysql Users for those databases.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy user priviledges with MySQL?](http://serverfault.com/questions/105612/how-to-copy-user-priviledges-with-mysql)

Comment: See the linked question where I provide a way to export the privilege information in a way that may be a bit cleaner then a export/import of the `mysql` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just export *mysql* database - it contains all permissions and account information with hashed passwords.

Comment: Depending on the version differences and how you go about it a pure export/import of the database may not be what you want.  The schema for the privilege tables has changed over time.