# MySQL equivalent of `su - someuser` to assume identity of another user?

Tags: mysql

I run a MySQL server and I have MySQL root-level privileges on this instance:

```
mysql> select CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
mysql>
```

I am troubleshooting MySQL privileges for a series of users. I do not know the passwords for these users. As the MySQL root user, can I assume the identity of another user without knowing their password?

In the Linux/Unix world, I would do this with a command like 'su - someuser' to assume the identity of the user. Does MySQL provide an equivalent function?

Comment: Great question. I've never heard of such a thing, but will be quite interested to see if indeed there is.

Comment: Oh, and BTW...sysadmin/parent here as well. :)

Comment: The only way I know of doing something like this would be to safely store the user's password hash then set a new password and when you're finished put the hash back as it was. Obviously, the user gets locked out while you do this.

Comment: Thanks Iain. That's what I normally do, but I was hoping for something quicker. `su - jane` on Unix is a super quick and simple solution and I am hoping to find something like this on MySQL.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski: I don't think that exists you could always clone the privs to another account http://serverfault.com/questions/105612/how-to-copy-user-privileges-with-mysql

Comment: Yes, this has existed since MySQL 5.5. I added an answer for it.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for can only be done in two ways

## PROXY USERS

MySQL 5.5 introduced [**proxy users**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/proxy-users.html)

> When authentication to the MySQL server occurs by means of an authentication plugin, the plugin may request that the connecting (external) user be treated as a different user for privilege-checking purposes. This enables the external user to be a proxy for the second user; that is, to have the privileges of the second user. In other words, the external user is a “proxy user” (a user who can impersonate or become known as another user) and the second user is a “proxied user” (a user whose identity can be taken on by a proxy user).

You can find the defined proxy users in mysql.proxies_priv:

```
mysql> desc mysql.proxies_priv;
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Host         | char(60)   | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| User         | char(16)   | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| Proxied_host | char(60)   | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| Proxied_user | char(16)   | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| With_grant   | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| Grantor      | char(77)   | NO   | MUL |                   |                             |
| Timestamp    | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.22 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is [sample code from the MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/proxy-users.html)

```
CREATE USER 'empl_external'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH auth_plugin AS 'auth_string';
CREATE USER 'employee'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'employee_pass';
GRANT PROXY
  ON 'employee'@'localhost'
  TO 'empl_external'@'localhost';
```

## SECURITY TYPE (STORED PROCEDURES/VIEWS)

In `mysql.proc`, there is a column called `security_type`. With views, this exists in `information_schema.views`. It has two values 1) `invoker` and 2) `definer`. If a stored procedure has `security_type` as `definer`, you have the same access rights as the owner of the stored procedure. Of course, this is only applicable

- when calling a Stored Procedure or SELECTing from a View
- You have the [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) privilege

Comment: Thanks again Rolando. This looks like a good solution when a long term solution is needed (And I could use this elsewhere). For my one-off tests, I will probably chose a simpler solution like copying the privileges to a temporary user with a password that I do know.